# Diaglogflow entity different values with the same synonym can bot ask for clarification?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

Under the category of User I have two entries that have the same synonym.  If this synonym is the same for two of the entries is it possible for the dialogflow to ask which entry I want?

> DialogFlow Entity Entry Screen

[image: DialogFlow Entity Entry Screen]

When the chat bot prompts for the User and John is said the bot will then answer with something like `Which John? 123 or 321?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think  what you are doing now will work. dialog flow wont be able to detect which entity you want to use. that you should do with your business logic. one thing you can do is you can create a intent for

> Which John? 123 or 321?

and invoke that from the Response of your webhook using followupEventInput.

```
"followupEventInput": {
    "name": "event name",
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "parameters": {
      "param": "param value"
    }
  }
```

https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#sample_response_from_the_service

or you can use events. events is a feature that allows you to invoke intents by an event name instead of a user query.

https://dialogflow.com/docs/events

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Dialogflow alone. You could implement this in your backend, but then you would loose the benefit of the [Developer Mapping Entity](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities#dev_mapping), which is to give you a primary key (the reference value) without requiring further processing on your part. It might then be simpler to just get the user input with a `@sys.any` parameter and to do all the id matching in your backend.